# memory allocator - issue while traversing the memory

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have written simple memory allocator and I am running into issue where in I don't think I am accessing memory elements as I am thinking :) and I am unable to figure out the bug. Two issues which are there again from output side , there would be more which I wont be aware of.

Issues - 
1) while(block->next != NULL) crashes when it reaches next block 
2) In free   memptr->size comes up zero.

I haven't tried to look into memory alignment or fragmentation aspect, goal was to get something simple working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define length 10000

char memory[length] = {0};

typedef struct MEMBLOCK
{
  struct MEMBLOCK *next;
  int size;   
  bool is_available;
}memblock;

int remain_memory = length;

memblock* ptrlastblock;
memblock* endOfBlock(memblock *block);
void* allocMemory(memblock *block, int size);
void* xmalloc(size_t size);
void myfree(void *ptr);


int main(void) 
{
  int *ptr = (int *)xmalloc(10);
  if (ptr == NULL)
  {
    printf("memory allocation failed \n");
  }
  else
  {
    *ptr = 4;
  }
 // myfree(ptr);
  int *ptr1 = (int *)xmalloc(10);
  myfree(ptr1);

  return 0;
}

void* xmalloc(size_t size)
{
  memblock *block = (memblock*) memory;  // point to head of memory region
  return allocMemory(block, size);
}

void* allocMemory(memblock *block, int size)
{
  if (remain_memory == length)  // if no memory used allocate block
  {
    block->next = NULL;            
    block->is_available = false;
    block->size = size;
    ptrlastblock = endOfBlock(block); // point it to beginning of next block
    remain_memory -= size;
    return (void *)block + 1;  // increment block so pointing to begining of memory post block
  }

  if(remain_memory > size)
  {
      while(block->next != NULL)  // keep incrementing till you find 
      {                             // last used chunk
       block = block->next;
      }
    block = endOfBlock(block);
    block->next = NULL;
    block->size = size;
    block->is_available = false;
    remain_memory -= size;
    return (void *)block + 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return NULL;
  }

}

memblock* endOfBlock(memblock *block)
{
  memblock* eofblock = (memblock*)((size_t)(block + 1) + (size_t)block->size);
  return eofblock;
}

void myfree(void *ptr)
{
  memblock *memptr = (memblock *)ptr - 1;
  if (memptr->is_available == false)
  {
    memptr->is_available = true;
    printf(" memory with pointer is %d \n", memptr->size);
    remain_memory += memptr->size;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is that crazy comment style? If I understand correctly it will deference your `block` twice. Is that intended?

Comment: @EugeneSh. - I have added more comment on the code. Sorry didnt get your question completely

Comment: Right after `if(remain_memory > size)` there is a double `**`, which is not a part of a comment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Ah , I guess I tried to make that part bold and it didnt take it properly. Have uncommented that section - to remove any confusion.

Comment: A non-allocated char array cannot be reinterpreted as any other type.

Comment: Why do you think it is OK to cast your `memory` into `memblock` type?

Comment: @2501 I think it's the opposite... Any type  can be aliased as char  and vice versa...

Comment: Anyway. Your `memory` is the actual memory you are allocating, right? Not the storage for the metadata...

Comment: @EugeneSh. No. Any type can be aliased as char, but not every type can alias char. In fact only char can alias char.

Comment: Logic I have used is block aka metadata points to starting of allocated memory. Every time while you return memory for xmalloc you go increment block to the starting of that address

Comment: @2501 Can't any type alias a proper-sized char array?

Comment: @2501 - R u suggesting I cannot do "memblock *block = (memblock*) memory;" this in my code ?

Comment: @oneday I don't see where you are accounting for it anyway... I suggest you to draw it on a paper.

Comment: @EugeneSh. no it can't. Only `char*` can alias anything (discounting compatible types).

Comment: @EugeneSh.  My attempt to do accounting for it - is with this line in code "return (void *)block + 1;  // increment block so pointing to begining of memory post block"

Comment: @oneday Yes, you simply cannot do that if you intend to use C. Instead use allocated storage duration, i.e. malloc() (And read the C Standard).

Comment: @SergeyA Does it mean that if I alias a type `T` variable `t` with `char*`, I can't cast this `char*` back to `T*`?

Comment: @oneday At the very least you should fo `(void*)(block+1)`...

Comment: @EugeneSh. -  Thank u that was the bug !!! Phew - Thanks a ton !!

Comment: Anyway, I would suggest you to separate the metadata and the memory. Because right now just *any* write out of bounds will corrupt *everything*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Would it possible for you to put a snippet of what your saying to help me understand better. Because I dont think I understood your comment about separating metadata and memory completely

Comment: Perhaps not completely, but at least consolidate the metadata in a single place, not scattered around the whole "heap". But that's my opinion, which  you don't have to buy.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Understood now

Comment: @EugeneSh., you can cast back. Because original object type would still be T. It won't be aliasing.

Comment: @SergeyA That's a fine point here.. What if I `memcpy` this char* into another one and cast the result to `T`? Obviously 'll get a copy of it, and no one will say it is illegal. Or it is not aliasing as well?

Comment: @EugeneSh., what would you be `memcpy`ing it to? if you would be copying to object of type T, (aliased as anything else) it would be cool. Otherwise, it would be a violation.

Comment: @Sergey Really? So I can't `memcpy` it to a char array and cast it back as `T`? That's *very* fine point..  I should read the docs again...

Comment: @EugeneSh., your understanding is correct. What matters is original static type of the object.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that:

```
return (void *)block + 1;
```

is interpreted as:

```
((void *) block) + 1
```

since cast has higher priority than addition. You may be overwriting your `memblock` structure with `*ptr = 4;`.

[EDIT]

I think you should do what Eugene already suggested in comment:

```
return (void *) (block + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer - Yes you are right and I didnt know about that. So thanks for making me aware of that